# How to evaluate the following limit? $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\big(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}\big)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate the following limit? $$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}\right).$$

What I first did is multiply by the conjugate, but having trouble finishing the problem. I believe the final answer is $\tfrac23$.

**Edit:** Here's what I got so far

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that 
$$a^3-b^3=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^2+ab+b^2\right).$$
By taking $a=\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}$ we get 
$$\eqalign{\left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}^2+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}^2\right)=\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}^3-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}^3.
}$$
Hence
$$\eqalign{
\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}=\dfrac{2x^2}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}^2+\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}^2}
.}$$ Now divide top and bottom by $\tfrac1{x^2}$ to find 
$$\eqalign{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}=
\dfrac{2}{\sqrt[3]{\tfrac1x+1}^{2}+\sqrt[3]{\tfrac{-1}{x}+1}+\sqrt[3]{\tfrac{-1}x+1}^{2}},
}$$ thus the limit as $x\to\infty$ is as expected equal to $\tfrac23$.

Comment: I stated in the description of multiplying by the conjugate. After that is where I'm having trouble finishing the problem

Comment: @Gunz Look at my edit.

Comment: wouldn't x^3 / x^2 = x tho, not 1/x?

Comment: @Gunz No, one has $$\eqalign{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}^2\cdot\dfrac1{x^2}&=\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}^2}{x^2}\\&=\left(\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}}{x}\right)^2\\&=\left(          \dfrac      {\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}}{\sqrt[3]{x^3}}\right)^2\\&=\left(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{x^3+x^2}{x^3}}\right)^2\\&=\left(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac1x+1}\right)^2\\&=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac1x+1}^2.}$$

Comment: Ah i see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gunz You're welcome, glad I could help! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Put $t=\frac{1}{x}$, so that the limit $L=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}\right)$ becomes
$$
L=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+t}-\sqrt[3]{1-t}}{t}.
$$
observing that $a^{1/3}-b^{1/3}=\left(a-b\right)\underbrace{\left(a^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{ab}+b^{2/3}\right)}_c$ with $a=1+t$ and $b=1-t$
multiplying and dividing by $c$, we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+t}+\sqrt[3]{1-t}}{t}\cdot\frac{c}{c}=\ldots=\frac{1}{t}\frac{2t}{\sqrt[3]{(1+t)^2}+\sqrt[3]{1-t^2}+\sqrt[3]{(1+t)^2}}\to\frac{2}{3}\quad\text{for }t\to 0.
$$

Comment: I think the $+$ should be a $-$ in both instances of the expression $\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+t}+\sqrt[3]{1-t}}{t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want to evaluate a difference of functions which are asymptotic to each other, I find the most straightforward approach is to expand each as an asymptotic series and then look at the noncanceling terms. In this case:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(x^3+x^2)^{1/3}-(x^3-x^2)^{1/3}&=x(1+x^{-1})^{1/3}-x(1-x^{-1})^{1/3}\\
&=x \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/3}{k}x^{-k}-x \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/3}{k}(-x)^{-k}\\
&=(x + 1/3 + O(x^{-1})) - (x-1/3+O(x^{-1}))\\
&=2/3 + O(x^{-1})
\end{aligned}
$$

Less formally, we just need the approximation $(1+t)^\alpha\approx1+\alpha t$ for $t$ near $0$. So for large $x$, the quantity $x^{-1}$ is near $0$, so we have:
$$
x(1+x^{-1})^{1/3}-x(1-x^{-1})^{1/3} \approx
x(1+(1/3)x^{-1})-x(1-(1/3)x^{-1})=2/3
$$

Comment: That may be right, but I have no idea what those symbols mean. yet.

Comment: If you're interested, check out the [generalized binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) and [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 0):

HINT

I would say

$a=\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2},\quad b=\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2}$

$\displaystyle (a-b)\cdot \frac{a^2+ab+b^2}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\frac{2x^2}{a^2+ab+b^2}$

$\displaystyle \lim _{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\lim _{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2}{(x^3+x^2)^{2/3}+(x^3+x^2)^{1/3}(x^3-x^2)^{1/3}+b^2+(x^3-x^2)^{1/3}}=\cdots$

Answer (score -1):

If you use $(\cdots)^{1/3}+(\cdots)^{1/3}$ as the "conjugate" you cannot get $2x^2$ on the numerator.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2})&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2})((x^3+x^2)^{2/3}+(x^3-x^2)^{2/3})}{(x^3+x^2)^{2/3}+(x^3-x^2)^{2/3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^3+x^2-x^3+x^2}{(x^3+x^2)^{2/3}+(x^3-x^2)^{2/3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2x^2}{x^2(1+x^2/x^3)^{2/3}+x^2(1-x^2/x^3)^{2/3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{(1+1/x)^{2/3}+(1-1/x)^{2/3}}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: The limit is $2/3$.