# $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

this is like an idea, the procedure is longer. Can someone please tell me if this is ok or if there is a better solution (hopefully shorter)

---

\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2+1}\right) \\
&=\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+1} - \sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2+1}\\
&=\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt[3]{(x^3+x^2+1)^2} + \sqrt[3]{(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3-x^2+1)} + \sqrt[3]{(x^3-x^2+1)^2}}\\
&= \frac{2}{3}.
\end{align}

Comment: That works. Not much shorter, but you could first prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt[3]{x^3 + ax^2 + 1} - x = \frac{a}{3}$ then use it with $a = \pm 1$ to calculate 
$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+1} - x) - (\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2+1}-x)$.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom sorry, it's fixed now.

Comment: @dxiv interesting, I'll analyze it. Thank you

Comment: This is exactly the approach I would recommend, and I don't think it is long at all.

Comment: see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056128/how-to-evaluate-the-following-limit-lim-limits-x-to-infty-big-sqrt3x3?noredirect=1  ; the 1's in the arguments of the radicals don't affect the result in the "limit at infinity"

Answer (score 5):

Its right. Another thing you could do is try to use Taylor expansions, which I find works for many limit problems. First, write
$$ \sqrt[3]{x^3 \pm x^2 + 1} = x\sqrt[3]{1 \pm \frac1x+\frac1{x^3}}$$
and then the Taylor expansion $(1+h)^\alpha = 1 + \alpha h + o(h)$ as $h\to 0$ implies that as $x\to \infty$,
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{x^3 + x^2 + 1} -  \sqrt[3]{x^3 - x^2 + 1} 
&= x\left(\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac1x+\frac1{x^3}}-\sqrt[3]{1 - \frac1x+\frac1{x^3}}\right) \\
&= x\left(1 + \frac1{3x} + \frac1{3x^3} - \left[1 - \frac1{3x} + \frac1{3x^3}\right] + o\left(\frac1x\right)\right) \\
&= \frac23 + o(1).
\end{align}
Hence the limit is $\frac23$.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $x=\dfrac1z$ to rewrite the limit as a derivative:

$$\begin{align*}
& \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2+1}\right) \\
&= \lim_{z\to0^+} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1 + z + z^3} - \sqrt[3]{1 - z + z^3}}z \\
&= \frac d{dz} \left[\sqrt[3]{1 + z + z^3} - \sqrt[3]{1 - z + z^3}\right] \bigg|_{z=0} = \boxed{\frac23}
\end{align*}$$